# how to solve complex integration problem

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

While working on complex integration problem I got stuck at the following problem:

$\int \frac{|dz|}{|z-2|^2}$ where $|z| = 1$ is the domain.

The only idea that I am getting is that we can use the fact $z\bar{z} = 1$. Kindly help in solving the above problem. Thanks for giving time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

$$|z-2|^2 = (z-2) (\bar{z}-2) = |z|^2 - 4 \operatorname{Re}{z} + 4$$

so when $z=e^{i \phi}$, $|z-2|^2 = 5-4 \cos{\phi}$ and $|dz|=d\phi$, or

$$|z-2|^2 = 5-2 z - 2 z^{-1} $$
$$|dz|=-i \frac{dz}{z}$$

The integral is then equal to

$$\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{d \phi}{5-4 \cos{\phi}} = i \oint_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{2 z^2-5 z+2}$$

which is easily evaluated by the residue theorem.

Comment: sir, how did u get $$|dz|=-i \frac{dz}{z}$$. I got all other steps except this one. Kindly explain.

Comment: $$dz = i \, e^{i \phi} d\phi = i z \, d\phi$$

Comment: Got it sir. Thanks a lot for the nicely explained answer.